# Clause group by if two lines return the maximum

Tags: sql, group-by

My query is:

```
SELECT ID,B,C,D, SUM(X), SUM(Y)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
```

But if the query returns 2 lines with the same id, I want take only one line which have the max of column D.

For example if the query returns:

```
+----+---+---+---+--------+--------+
| ID | B | C | D | SUM(X) | SUM(Y) |
+----+---+---+---+--------+--------+
| 2  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 70     | 100    |
| 2  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 100    | 150    |
+----+---+---+---+--------+--------+
```

Then drop the line with D=1, and keep only the line with D=3

Comment: You usually GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to set functions.

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results and sample data.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Actually, i'm using SAS.

Comment: In your example B and D are equal in the two rows. What if they are different? Do you want only one result row per ID or per ID-B-C combination?

Comment: yes i want a combinaison ID-B-C-D, if there is more than one with the same ID, take only one that having the maximum D.

Comment: No, you haven't understood my question. Obviously you don't want a result row per ID-B-C-D combination, because this gives you the result shown. So if you have ID|B|C|D = 2|3|4|5 and 2|6|7|8, do you only want the second record (because same ID and greater D) or both (because different B and C)?

Comment: BTW: As far as I know SAS is software that works with various DBMS. So that can be Oracle or MySQL or SQL Server or any other RDBMS. Do you know which one you are using?

Comment: The second option, if the columns are different keep them, but if id, b,c are the same but only d is different then only keep the max.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per `id`, then that should be the only column in the `group by`:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(X), SUM(Y)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this not what i'm looking for. I want all the colummns, but if twp lignes by ID, i'll take the one with the max D and drop the others

Answer (score 0):

Put your query inside of a `CTE` and then filter the result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID,B,C,D, SUM(X) AS X, SUM(Y) AS Y
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID,B,C,D
)
SELECT * FROM CTE T
WHERE [D] = (SELECT MAX(D) FROM CTE where id = t.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show one row per ID/B/C combination. In case you find multiple results for one combination (ID=2, B=1, C=1 in your example), you want the one with the greatest D. So you must rank your aggregation results.

In standard SQL you rank your rows with `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` depending on what you want to do with ties. We don't know your DBMS, but many DBMS feature these functions, so just try.

```
select id, b, c, d, sum_x, sum_y
from
(
  select 
    id, b, c, d, sum(x) as sum_x, sum(y) as sum_y,
    row_number() over (partition by id, b, c order by d desc) as rnk
  from table
  group by id, b, c, d
) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` like this :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D, SUM(t1.X), SUM(t1.Y)
FROM TABLE1 t1
join (select ID, max(D) D from TABLE1 group by ID) t2 
on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.D=t2.D
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af277/4)